# Vertical alignment of table on a page with a section header

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment

I have a "Tables" section of the paper I'm writing. When I start the "Tables" section, for some reason, the table on the first page vertically aligns at the bottom of the page. How can I get it centered vertically? Below is code and a picture of the output. Using "[p]", which I had read elsewhere about, just moves it onto a different page.

```
\newpage\clearpage
\section{Tables}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \hline\hline
     & Broad LIS Sample & RD Analysis Sample \\
     \hline
     Avg. Age & 77.2 & 76.6 \\
     \% Female & 69.5\% & 69.1\% \\
     Avg. Elixhauser Index & 4.5 & 4.2 \\
     & & \\
     Total Drug Spending & & \\
     Mean & \$4,024 & \$3,707 \\
     25th Percentile & \$815 & \$710 \\
     Median & \$2,601 & \$2,384 \\
     75th Percentile & \$5,389 & \$5,021 \\
     & & \\
     Avg. Chronic Drug Spending & \$3,012 & \$2,821 \\
     Avg. Non-Drug Med. Spending & \$12,888 & \$10,945 \\
     & & \\
     \hline
     Observations & 4,628,704 & 1,989,603 \\
     \hline\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Summary statistics for samples used in our analysis.}
    \label{tab:sum_stats}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want a single table per page?

Comment: Yes. I'm not so concerned with the other tables--they vertically align correctly. I just want, for this table, it to vertically align centrally.

Comment: In this case, removing the table environment and using `{centering\vfill\begin{tabular}…\end{tabular}\captionof{table}{…}\vfill\null` should do the trick.

Comment: thank you! that did work!